# regarding the tensor shape is (?,?,?,1)

Tags: python, tensorflow

During debuging the Tensorflow code, I would like to output the shape of a tensor, say, `print("mask's shape is: ",mask.get_shape())`  However, the corresponding output is `mask's shape is (?,?,?,1)`  How to explain this kind of output, is there anyway to know the exactly value of the first three dimensions of this tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output means that TensorFlow's shape inference has only been able to infer a *partial shape* for the `mask` tensor. It has been able to infer (i) that `mask` is a 4-D tensor, and (ii) its last dimension is 1; but it does not know statically the shape of the first three dimensions.

If you want to get the actual shape of the tensor, the main approaches are:

1. Compute `mask_val = sess.run(mask)` and print `mask_val.shape`.
2. Create a symbolic `mask_shape = tf.shape(mask)` tensor, compute `mask_shape_val = sess.run(mask_shape)` and print `mask_shape.

Shapes usually have unknown components if the shape depends on the data, or if the tensor is itself a function of some tensor(s) with a partially known shape. If you believe that the shape of the mask **should be** static, you can trace the source of the uncertainty by (recursively) looking at the inputs of the operation(s) that compute `mask` and finding out where the shape becomes partially known.